# Dojo attach button like jQuery

Tags: jquery, dojo

In jQuery, if I want to attach button style to any tag, I can do this:

```
$("a").button();
```

how do I attach button style using dojo to any tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible equivalent of your jQuery in dojo:

```
// Select all 'a' tags.
dojo.query('a').forEach(function(element) {

    // Attach a button to each 'a' tag.
    var button = new dijit.form.Button({
        onClick: function(){ location.href = element.href; }
    }, element);
    button.startup();
});
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/rLtNq/.  Note the inclusion of the `claro.css` file, and as noted by mydoghasworms, you'll need to `dojo.require` the button class.

Comment: After reading mydoghasworms's answer, I came up with a solution very similar to what you are using. Although mydog's answer is very detailed and good, yours is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Dojo way is to declaratively or programatically create elements. Here is a declarative example of creating a button using the dojoType attribute:

```
<input id="button1" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" label="Do it!"/>
```

Here is a programmatic example, whereby a button is created and inserted into the DOM:

```
var button = new dijit.form.Button({ label: "Click me!"}, "node_id");
```

The object passed as the first argument contains properties to instantiate the control (our button in this case). The second argument is the DOM node where the new element will be inserted (or attached to, rather - the original node is pretty much replaced).

For another example (specifically for Buttons, but the concept is similar, see http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/Button.html#dijit-form-button)

As for your question about using "any" tag (not sure if that is what you were getting at), you could define any HTML tag with an ID and replace it with a button using these methods. E.g.:

```
<h3 id="button1" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" label="Do it!"></h3>
```

would also be parsed by Dojo and work.

If you are new to Dojo, you should be aware that the approach is quite different if you are coming from jQuery. Instead of including Javascript files in your HTML, Dojo has a very modular system for including code, using dojo.require(), so for example, you would have to specify dojo.require("dijit.form.Button") after including dojo.js (and specify the following attribute

```
djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"
```

in your script tag for including dojo.js to have the dijit widgets parsed automatically).